# treeview size in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview, scrollbar

Please let me know how can I re-size height of tree view control when screen resolution is changed?

please see this code:

```
<TreeView  Name="treeView1" Height="150" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Root" IsExpanded="True">
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 1"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 2"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 3"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 4"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 5"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 6"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 7"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 8"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 9"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 10"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 11"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 12"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 13"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 14"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 15"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 16"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 17"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 18"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 19"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 20"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 21"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 22"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 23"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 24"></TreeViewItem>
        <TreeViewItem Header="Item 24"></TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

in some screen resolutions I can see all nodse and in some resolutions I see a scroll bar.
I want to see all nodes without scroll bar.

Comment: You won't be able to do that when changing the *resolution* - the pixel size is physically larger in a lower resolution, so you have fewer dots on the same physical viewport - this is why you get the scrollbar.

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this, using [SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.systemevents.displaysettingschanged.aspx) Event:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public static EventHandler HandleDisplaySettingsChanged = 
        new EventHandler(SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged);

    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Microsoft.Win32.SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged += HandleDisplaySettingsChanged;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        SystemEvents.DisplaySettingsChanged -= HandleDisplaySettingsChanged;
    }

    public static void SystemEvents_DisplaySettingsChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("display settings changed");

        // change treeview size as you think what is appropriate here...
    }
}
```